# How to store a series of vectors from a for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, matrix, integer

I have a for loop which generates a vector. i want to store these vectors in a matrix. 
normally i would do:

```
for r=1:100

   vec=[x:y]+r;

   mat(:,r)=vec

end
```

But this doesnt work, because i have something like:

```
dr=10/20

for r=1:dr:20

    vec=[x;y]+r;

  ...
```

How  would I store the vectors in a matrix now? Because i cant use r for the column indices, because the values of r arent integers most of the time.

Comment: Preallocate `r` as `r=1:dr:20;`. Then use `for f=1:lenght(r)`. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many options eg:

```
r=1:dr:20
for rr=1:length(r)

    vec=[x;y]+r(rr);
    mat(:,rr)=vec;
...
```

or

```
col = 1;
for r=1:dr:20

    vec=[x;y]+r;
    mat(:,col)=vec;
    col = col + 1;
    ....
```

But whatever you choose you must preallocate `mat` before your for loop like this:

```
mat = zeros(length(x) + length(y), length(1:dr:20))
```

Pre-allocation is essential when using loops in Matlab or they will run very inefficiently.

Comment: Thank you very much. The col=col+1 one did work. I knew it was something so easy..

Comment: @Fl.pf. no problem, although I think the first one is neater imo

Comment: yeah but that one made problems. The calculation is more complex then the example i wrote :) maybe i get it to run, i will try